# codecept generate:cept acceptance Welcome does not create any file

Tags: codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm totally new to codeception and I'm just after installing it into my yii2 project. 
First I run: `alias codecept="./vendor/bin/codecept"`
Then I run: `codecept bootstrap`
and then: `codecept generate:cept acceptance SmokeTest`

and I don't see SmokeTestCept.php file in tests/codeception/acceptance. I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help please?

Comment: Codeception prints the full path to the file that was created, please try again and check the output. The path you used is non-standard, the standard is `tests/acceptance`.

Comment: Under tests/ the only folder I have is codeception and two files codeception.yml and README.md. The codeception folder contains config files as well as other folders ie. for unit, functional and acceptance tests.

Comment: Try to create a new cept and check the output.